# How to center container vertically on a site with a Navbar without fixed-top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to center container vertically on a site with a Navbar without fixed-top in Bootstap5?

this is my code: the content is centered but there appears a scrollbar...

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100">
  <div class="container text-center">
    I am centered vertically, but a scrollbar apears because of the Navbar?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have min-vh-100 applied, that assigns your div a minimum height of 100 viewport height. viewport height is the entire window - including the navbar. Either remove the (fixed) navbar height with ```calc(100vh - 30px)``` (for example), or wrap the navbar and jumbotron in a div that has min-vh-100, then set jumbotron height to 100%.

Or you use percentages/vh exclusively, instead of fixed measurements.

Comment: I try to wrap the navbar and jumbotron in a div as you as you suggested. But it doesn't work. Can you give me an example please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```